# Change image with button next/previous in a Scroll View in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I change the next image with buttons while images are loading dynamically in Unity3D using C#.

```
 public void NextPictureInGallery()
    { 
        int i=0;//index of image
        if(i + 1 < image.Length)
        {
            i++;
        }
     }
```

[image]

Images are in a Scroll view

Comment: Show some code what you have tried

Comment: @RasaMohamed I put a few lines and an image to describe what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [normalized position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-normalizedPosition.html) of your ScrollRect.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Sprite[] myImage; // Its length descried in Inspector and assign sprite images
public Button myBtn;
int i=0;
void Update()
{
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // HeresI'm checking condition for Mouse Input,  Change this based on your 
  {    
    if(i+1 < myImage.Length)
    {
     //Make sure it is added in the Inspector.
     myBtn.image.sprite = myImage[i];
     i++;
    }
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761021/4-6-new-ui-how-to-change-button-image)

Check and let me know

Comment: not working, but I don't want to change picture of next button, I want to change Image like when drag with mouse in scrollview, increment by one current image.

Comment: you mean dragging image from one button to button...!

Comment: when click button in center screen I want to see image 3 like in picture.

Comment: Can you show up your code here till now what you tried, so that I could help you easily