# Change button sprites in scrollview in Unity 5.2

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I have a scroll view with lots of buttons on it. when i press one button, that button needs to change the sprite and stay like that. if any other button (or same one) is pressed previous button needs to revert back to original sprite.. 
here is some example

[image]

button 2 was pressed and changed sprite, it stays like that untill it is pressed again or any other (in this case button 3) is pressed

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/967366/how-to-change-button-image-on-new-ui.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [4.6 New UI How to change Button Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761021/4-6-new-ui-how-to-change-button-image)

Comment: So much salt here, no its not that question, please read it..  I dont need 1 button to change sprite, i need group of them, and need them to first stay changed untill pressed again or any other button from same group was pressed

Comment: I solved the problem using toggle group and toggles.
Its really easy and very versatile..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a draft of a possible solution. Create a manager script for the "buttons group" and attach the script on the scrollview

```
public class ButtonsGroupController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // List of all children buttons 
    private readonly List<Button> _buttons;

    // Last pressed button index
    private int _lastId = -1;

    void Start(){

        // Look for all buttons (children of this GO - scrollview)
        _buttons = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();

        // Add event listener for buttons
        for(var i = 0; i < _buttons.Count; i++){
            var index = i;
            _buttons[index].onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonPressed(index));
        }

    }

    // Resolve buttons press event
    private void ButtonPressed(int index){
        // The same button has been pressed
        if(_lastId == index)
            return;

        // Update the last selected button sprite - to normal state
        // _buttons[_lastId]....

        // Update the last id
        _lastId = index;

        // Update the sprite of newly pressed button
        // _buttons[_lastId]....
    }
}
```